# Does the passive skill Unity apply to your follower/mystic ally?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Unity currently reads:

`Each ally affected by your Mantras increases your damage by 5%, up to a maximum of 20%, and has 5% increased damage.`

Does Unity apply to your follower and/or to your Mystic Ally?

If that is, do I get 15% damage increase when I am playing with another monk that also uses Mystic Ally?

Comment: I would say yes in both cases but you would get 15% with another monk with Mystic Ally since that makes 3 allies (your Mystic Ally, the other monk and his/her Mystic Ally)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau oh yeah ofcourse, I edited it.

Comment: Your question had me search if Inna's set bonus (all 4 mantras) worked with resolve and it [looks like it](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13567677022)... I need my 4th piece asap or the Royale Ring.

Comment: 100% yes to follower, not sure about mystic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I tested it.

With unity:

- Dps is increased with a follower.
- Dps stays the same with just my mystic ally.
- Dps with follower and a mystic ally is the same as point 1.

So a `Mystic Ally` doesn't count as an ally with the passive skill Unity.